# Pod ephemeral local storage usage exceeds the total limit of containers

Tags: kubernetes, tekton

All the pods started by my Tekton Pipelines get evicted by kubernetes because of the following reason:

Pod ephemeral local storage usage exceeds the total limit of containers 0.

I do not use ephemeral storage and therefore I haven't set a value. How can this situation be resolved when I don't want ephemeral storage but kubernetes sets 0 as a default?

Comment: Tekton Pods would use emptyDirs. Check for resourcequotas in your namesiace, maybe. Although such limitation could also be set at the container runtime level. Either way: for sure that's another configuration in your cluster, blocking you here.

Answer (score 0):

For pod-level isolation the kubelet works out an overall Pod storage limit by summing the limits for the containers in that Pod. In this case, if the sum of the local ephemeral storage usage from all containers and also the Pod's emptyDir volumes exceeds the overall Pod storage limit, then the kubelet also marks the Pod for eviction.

if the kubelet is not measuring local ephemeral storage, then a Pod that exceeds its local storage limit will not be evicted for breaching local storage resource limits.

Note that by default, if you have not set any limits on ephemeral-storage the pod has access to the entire disk of the node it is running on.

Refer to this link on [Requests and Limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#requests-and-limits).